# How to setup .net core web-api controller which used every few seconds

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, singleton, webapi

A general conceptual question:
I'm having a .net core 2.2 web-api server which has a controller with a get method which should be used every few seconds (lets say - every 10 seconds) - I wonder what is the best option to deal with this scenario:

1. Leave the controller life cycle as it is - meaning - initiate it on every request and let the framework deal with it (destructor, garbage collector, etc).
2. Make the controller singleton in the server scope, initiate it at the server startup and use this instance on every request.

Comment: the best option is don't care about how frequently the action is accessed. So let it be handled by the framework. Why do you need to care about this? for performance? resource saving? Have you even tried benchmarking it? Every 10 seconds is not so frequent and in fact many actions can be accessed thousands of times per second (and of course the controller is just instantiated in the standard way, for each request).

Comment: you should focus on optimizing the core logic inside the actions, rather than trying to make the controller a singleton.